# Why can't I access the NSApp global variable from a controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am inside of a controller, and would like to access and close the currently displayed mainWindow.  But when I try:

```
[NSApp mainWindow] close];
```

nothing happens.  So how do I access it?

Comment: I’ve never seen `NSApp` being `nil`. Is `-[NSApplication sharedApplication]` `nil`, too? Have you tried `NSLog()`ing it instead of using the debugger?

Comment: How would I check if [NSApplication sharedApplication] is nil?  I'm assuming that I can use NSApp without declaring it? And I don't know how to NSLog objects, just strings.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"NSApp = %@", NSApp); NSLog(@"sharedApp: %@", [NSApplication sharedApplication]);`. The `%@` format specifier can be used to format objects.

Comment: Ah, they both are returning addresses.  I had just been mousing over "NSApp" before and it had been saying it was an unknown object.  So do you know why this is not closing the active window?

Comment: Does `-mainWindow` return `nil`? Also, see if `-orderOut:` works.

Comment: I just want to point something out here: `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` will create the application if it was nil, so `nil` will only be returned on error.

Comment: Thanks for the help bavarious, just being able to view object states in NSLog will help immensely with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use something like:

```
 [[NSApp delegate] closeFilePanel];
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the question. If `NSApp` were `nil`, you wouldn't be able to send any message to it, not `mainWindow` nor `delegate` nor any other.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, I discovered that NSApp actually wasn't nil.  I've updated the question.